# How to pass parameters from one function to the next

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am having trouble passing my id parameters to my process function. When I load the page it runs automatically for some reason without having to click the submit button and then if I try to add new info on my form it does not do anything. I would really like to pass the parameters from the init function on submit.

```
function process(first, last, dept) {
    'use strict';


     return false;
} // End of process() function.

// Initial setup:
function init() {
    'use strict';
    $('theForm').onsubmit = process('firstName', 'lastName', 'department');
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing

```
$('theForm').onsubmit = process('firstName', 'lastName', 'department');
```

do

```
$('theForm').onsubmit = function(){
    process('firstName', 'lastName', 'department');
}
```

Right now, you are calling the process function at the start of your program and assigning its return value as the onsubmit handler. In the end your current version is equivalent to this:

```
process('firstName', 'lastName', 'department');
$('theForm').onsubmit = false;
```

Instead, what you want to do is have the onsubmit event handler be a function that calls proccess.

Comment: OK got it! One other thing is that once it runs, the message to output comes on but than immediately disappears.

Comment: Thats probably because the page is being reloaded when you submit the form. A quick hack might be putting the message in an `alert()` box but I don't think its a good idea overall to pause the form submission to show a message... why not show the message on the response page?

Comment: The message is supposed to show on the response page. Its supposed to take in the information and then display the info as a message, when I click submit, it does that but then reloads itself again which is confusing.

Comment: I figured it out, had to return false

Answer (score 0):

You could also do...

```
$('theForm')
     .onsubmit = process.bind(window, 'firstName', 'lastName', 'department');
```

If your target platforms don't support `bind()`, you can [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).